# 親要素のイベントハンドラを先に発動させたい

Tags: javascript

```js
function aaa(){
  alert("aaa");
}

function bbb(){
   alert("bbb");
}
```

```html
<html>
<table>
  <tr onclick="aaa();">
    <td><button  onclick=" bbb();">ボタン</button></td>
    <td>適当な文字列</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

ボタンを押したとき、
動作が,bbb()→aaa()となるのですが、
これを、aaa()→bbb()と発動される順番を指定することはできないでしょう？

ただし、"適当な文字列"にクリックしたときは、aaa()は発動したままです。
また、以下もダメです。(いまは単純化してるだけなので・・)

```html
<td><button  onclick="aaa();bbb();">ボタン</button></td>
   <td onclick="aaa();">適当な文字列</td>
```

ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

この順番（bbb→aaa）で関数が呼ばれるのは、デフォルトのイベントハンドラの実行タイミングが、DOMのイベント伝播システムでいうバブリングフェーズ；発火点を起点に上向き（親要素側）に進行するときであるためです（[参考](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)）。これを上位（親要素）側からの進行時点（キャプチャフェーズ）で実行することを指定する場合には、addEventListenerの第三引数[*useCapture*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)にtrueを渡してイベントハンドラを登録します。
なお、こうしたイベント伝播を考慮しない書き方も可能で、この場合は基本的に上位（親要素）側にだけイベントハンドラを設定しておいて、発火点をEventオブジェクトのtargetプロパティから取得して動作を分岐させる方法があります。

```js
const aaa = function() {
    console.log('aaa')
};
const bbb = function() {
    console.log('bbb')
};

const $target = document.querySelector('#target');
const $button = document.querySelector('#button');

$target.addEventListener('click', aaa, true);
$button.addEventListener('click', bbb, false);

/*
// alternative
$target.addEventListener('click', e => {
    aaa();
    if (e.target === $button) {
        bbb();
    }
});
*/
```

```html
<html>
<table>
  <tr id="target">
    <td><button id="button">ボタン</button></td>
    <td>適当な文字列</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```